# What is the event of textboxes in silverlight when it loses focus?

Tags: silverlight

Html has the onblur event. What is the equivalent for Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UIElement.LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Simple but efficient answer ;)